# How to use ByteBuddy delegation for intercepting bootstrap class method

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy, javaagents

I'm using java agent and bytebuddy to intercept the "read" and "write" methods in FileIOStreams. A feature to implement is "to call the original methods under certain circumstances, else pass". Due to this, I need to have full control of the invoking flow using method delegation instead of wrapping it with Advice.

The method interception works fine when @Morph is not there, but it does not work when I add @Morph to parameters. I have tested with some other annotations:

adding @AllArguments, @This will not block the delegation, the method will run as my interceptor;

adding @Morph, @SuperCall will block the delegation. No exception will be thrown: the original method will run as what it used to be.

Here is the code I want to implement:

```
public static void mountAgent(Instrumentation inst) {

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.REDEFINITION)
                .with(AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
                .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
                .ignore(new AgentBuilder.RawMatcher.ForElementMatchers(nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy.").or(isSynthetic()), any(), any()))
                .with(new AgentBuilder.Listener.Filtering(
                        new StringMatcher("java.io.FileInputStream", StringMatcher.Mode.EQUALS_FULLY)
                                .or(new StringMatcher("java.io.FileOutputStream", StringMatcher.Mode.EQUALS_FULLY)),
                        AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut()))
                .type(named("java.io.FileOutputStream"))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                    @Override
                    public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder,
                                                            TypeDescription typeDescription,
                                                            ClassLoader classLoader,
                                                            JavaModule module) {
                        return builder.method(named("write").and(not(isNative())).and(takesArgument(0, byte[].class)))
                                .intercept(MethodDelegation
                                        .withDefaultConfiguration()
                                        .withBinders(Morph.Binder.install(Morphing.class))
                                        .to(WriteInterceptor.class));
                    }})
                .installOn(inst);
    }
```

(Code for appending interceptors to BootstrapClassLoaderSearch is skipped)

And following is my interceptors:

```
public interface Morphing<T> {
        T Object invoke(Object[] agrs);
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static class WriteInterceptor {
    @RuntimeType
    public static void write(
//change the input here
            byte[] bytes,
            @AllArguments Object[] args,
            @Morph Morphing<Void> morphing
    ) throws Exception {
        if (true) {
            morphing.invoke(args);
        }
        else {
            // do something
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

If the input of intercepting function is empty or only byte[] bytes, the delegation will work and Exception is thrown:

```
[Byte Buddy] IGNORE java.io.FileInputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] COMPLETE java.io.FileInputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] DISCOVERY java.io.FileOutputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM java.io.FileOutputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] COMPLETE java.io.FileOutputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]

Exception: java.lang.Exception thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

If the input is

> byte[] bytes, @AllArguments Object[] args, @Morph Morphing morphing

or

> @AllArguments Object[] args, @Morph Morphing morphing

the built-in write function is called and the output is

```
[Byte Buddy] IGNORE java.io.FileInputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] COMPLETE java.io.FileInputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] DISCOVERY java.io.FileOutputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM java.io.FileOutputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] COMPLETE java.io.FileOutputStream [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
```

What's the reason that the delegation does not work after adding @Morph, but bytebuddy still says transform is completed? How to get the correct morphing for this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your retransformation is already failing. Did you try to add a listener to the retransformation process. What does *Exception: java.lang.Exception thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"* mean?

One thing that I noticed is that you do not adjust the module graph. The *java.base* module will not be able to see your interceptor which is most likely loaded in the unnamed module of the bootstrap loader. Did you try to add *assureReadEdgeTo* in your transformation where you point to your interceptor class?

Also, please note that `Advice` does allow you to skip or even repeat a method execution. Have a look at the javadoc of the enter or exit methods. Typically, when instrumenting bootstrap classes advice tends to be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I did  omit to check the arguments in Advice.OnMethodEnter. I really appreciate your work on bytebuddy! It's so friendly to people know nothing about java byte code like me